# Line integral answer confirmation please :). I have moved the actual question to the first line.

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

> My question: Am I meant to sub in something for $x$ and $y$ below?
>
> I believe I have now obtained the correct answer: $\oint_C \mathrm{F\cdot T \;ds} \;= 4xy + 4x^2 - 4xy - 4x^2 = 0 $

The working below:

---

---

Consider the vector field:

> $F(x,y) = xy \;\boldsymbol{i} + x^2 \;\boldsymbol{j} $

Let $C$ be the rectangle with vertices $(0,0),(3,0),(3,1),(0,1)$, let $T$ denote the unit tangent vector to $C$ directed anticlockwise around $C$.

Calculating:

> $\oint_C \mathrm{F\cdot T \;ds}$

I want to do this directly without Green's Theorem

My attempt:

Parameters:

$$\begin{align}
\\r_1(t) =  \left(\frac{3t}4,0\right), 0\leq t\leq 4
\\r_2(t) =  \left(3,\frac t4\right), 0\leq t\leq 4
\\r_3(t) =  \left(3-\frac{3t}4, 1\right), 0\leq t\leq 4
\\r_4(t) =  \left(0, 1 - \frac t4\right), 0\leq t\leq 4
\end{align}$$

Which using $T(t) = \frac{r(t)}{||r(t)||}$, we get:
$$\begin{align}
\\T_1(t) =  \left(1,0\right)
\\T_2(t) =  \left(0,1\right)(*),
\\T_3(t) =  \left(-1,0\right)(*),
\\T_4(t) =  \left(0, -1\right)
\end{align}$$

$\oint_C \mathrm{F\cdot T \;ds} = \int_0^4 xy \mathrm{ds} + \int_0^4 x^2\; \mathrm{ds} + \int_0^4 -xy \;\mathrm{ds} + \int_0^4 -x^2\; \mathrm{ds}$

$ \;= 4xy + 4x^2 - 4xy - 4x^2 = 0 $

Therefore this path was conservative.

Comment: don't need to get the tangent vector, just take $dr$ .. and I think you can parametrize your lines better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure why you always want $0\le t \le 4$ but you are free to choose this if you so desire.

The work is then (for each segment):

$$\int_0^4 \textbf{F}(\textbf{r}(t)) \textbf{. r}'(t) \mathrm{d}t$$

i.e. substitute $x$ and $y$ in terms of $t$ into $\textbf{F}$ for the given segment, dot product with the time derivative of $\textbf{r}(t)$ and integrate over the domain of $t$ you have chosen.

Comment: Is there a way to do this via the unit tangent vector? I think I am missing something? Is $\oint_C F \cdot T ds = \int F(r(t)) \cdot r't(t) dt$?

Comment: I've actually just noticed that you defined your tangent vector incorrectly. It should be defined in terms of the \emph{derivative} of $\textbf{r}(t)$ i.e.$\textbf{r}'(t)$. In response to your above comment though, yes the integrals are equivalent (excusing a small typo in the rhs where you have a random $t$ included)

Comment: Ahaha nice catch on that typo xD. So the tangent vector has: $T(t) = \frac{r'(t)}{||r'(t)||}$ which honestly makes the question seem possible to solve now, thank you for that. I will have another go at it!!

Comment: Exactly right. Note the denominator will be cancelled out by the change of integration variable from $s$ to $t$ (assuming you make this change).